# building a dynamic query to insert data into table

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @qry nvarchar(100)
declare @Id int
declare @pth varchar(100)
set @Id=4
set @pth='abc'
set @qry='insert into pic_data(o_id,path) values('+@Id+','+@pth+')'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @qry
```

i'm trying to do this, but error occurred

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'insert into
>   pic_data(o_id,path) values(' to data type int." after that i cast the
>   id to varchar then another error came "Invalid column name 'abc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes for the varchar..

```
 declare @qry nvarchar(100)
    declare @Id int
    declare @pth varchar(100)
    set @Id=4
    set @pth='abc'
    set @qry='insert into pic_data(o_id,path) values('+cast(@Id as varchar)+','''+@pth+''')'
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @qry
```

Comment: hi, but why this same thing is not working in function?

Comment: use the same code in stored procedure. Function doesn't support dynamic queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @PTH VARCHAR(100)
set @Id=4
set @pth='abc'


SET @qry='INSERT INTO PIC_DATA(O_ID,PATH) VALUES('+CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR(10))+','+''''+@pth+''''+')'
Print @qry
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @qry
```